# iPhone HARDCODING a swipe

Tags: iphone

Basically, we either have remote access to the iPhone or the phone is connected to a network where we can control the phone (send it messages etc.) How can I simulate a swipe without touching the actual phone? I know there are Swipe Recognizers, but I haven't found a way to HARDCODE coordinates to simulate a swipe; for example, without touching the phone, perform the swipe to unlock.

Comment: That's not possible, the way you describe it. Such simulations can't be done. You have to call the methods of the swipe recognizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A swipe is input. You'd normally recognize the swipe, either with a gesture recognizer or by handling the touch directly, and then perform some sort of action. If you want to simulate a swipe, just perform the action that would be performed if the user made the equivalent gesture.

For example, if a swipe would normally switch to a different view, simply call the method that switches to that view. If possible, do it with animation so that the user has some visual indication of what's going on.

Comment: So swipes are only possible with the actual device. Thanks guys. I thought since you could read the coordinates of the swipe, that you could go the other way around and tell it what coordinates to swipe to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that what you are trying to do is possible, unless maybe with a script in the Automation instrument.  However, if the iPhone is jailbroken, you could install Veency and connect the phone through any VNC client and interact with it that way.